# NameError: name 'threading' is not defined will running Python Program in Terminal

Tags: python

I have imported the following modules in my python file:-

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
```

But, I am still getting this error:-

```
NameError: name 'threading' is not defined
```

It is showing the error on this line:-

```
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
```

Could anyone please let me know how could I resolve this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import `from threading import *` you have to access the methods directly, without calling the class `threading` before. So you just import every method from threading and just use them:

```
from threading import *
receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
```

otherwise import and then refer to the module itself

```
import threading
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
```

Answer (score -3):

## import socket programming library

```
import socket 
  
# import thread module 
from _thread import *
import threading 
  
print_lock = threading.Lock()
```

Comment: How is that related to the question?